# Google sheets long URLs

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google sheet that generates URLs from the values in cells. When the generated URL is short, the text produced is blue, underlined, and functions as a link to the URL. When the generated URL is long, the text produced is black and not a link.

URL that is formatted as a link:
http://www.google.com/search?q=Pax6+gene

URL that is not formatted as a link:
https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term=Pax6+AND+%28%28%22heart+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiac+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiac+morphogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22heart+morphogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22second+heart+field%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22outflow+tract+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiac+crescent%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22epicardial+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22first+heart+field%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiac+organogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22oft+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22heart+organogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22aortic+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22epicardium+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22endocardial+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22endocardium+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22mitral+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22inflow+tract+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22pulmonary+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22tricuspid+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22pulmonic+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22pro-epicardium+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22pro-epicardial+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22ift+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D%29+OR+%28%22congenital+heart+disease%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+AND+%22development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D%29%29&sort=date&size=200

The long URLs are generated using this code:

```
="https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/?term="&A2&"+AND+%28%28%22heart+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiac+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiac+morphogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22heart+morphogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22second+heart+field%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22outflow+tract+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiac+crescent%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22epicardial+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22first+heart+field%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22cardiac+organogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22oft+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22heart+organogenesis%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22aortic+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22epicardium+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22endocardial+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22endocardium+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22mitral+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22inflow+tract+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22pulmonary+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22tricuspid+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22pulmonic+valve+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22pro-epicardium+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22pro-epicardial+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+OR+%22ift+development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D%29+OR+%28%22congenital+heart+disease%22%5BAll+Fields%5D+AND+%22development%22%5BAll+Fields%5D%29%29&sort=date&size=200"
```

Is there a way to change this behavior?

Comment: _generates URLs from the values in cells_ Would you please edit your question to explain how hyperlinks are generating. I tested your data using several methods and can recreate your outcome only when pasting the long url directly into a cell or formula bar. Otherwise the following created blue hyperlinks for the long url: `SETFORMULA()`, `HYPERLINK()` (plain text url, separate label; url as label and no label) and `Insert>Insert link` using plain text url. On a tangent, have you considered that this could be a browser issue (FWIW, I'm using Chrome on Win10)?

Comment: Wrapping my formula in `hyperlink(...)` solved the problem. @Tedinoz, If you make this an answer I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to take a url and create a hyperlink in Google Sheets. Your urls vary from short (@40 characters) to very long (@1400 characters).

The `HYPERLINK()` function will create the hyperlinked-url. It is a built-in function. It should be noted that links can also be created manually from the Main menu - `Insert>Insert link`.

The syntax is `HYPERLINK(url,[link label])` [Doc ref](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093313?hl=en#null).

The link label is optional. In the examples below, there are four examples of using (or not using) the link label.

---

**HYPERLINK samples**

[image: sample]

---

Note (18 Nov 2020):
I had meant to mention that the hyperlink can also be created with an apps script using `setformula()`. I haven't included the script here, but happy to add if anyone would like it.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it appears that the automatic conversion to hyperlinks is capped at just over 1000 characters.

But you can create the hyperlink manually:

1. Copying the url
2. Right click on the cell
3. choose insert hyperlink
4. paste url

Comment: Is there a way I don't have to do this manually for 100s of rows?